# Can you recommend a game server for a facebook board game?

Tags: server

I am seeking a game server that will scale well. All commercial and/or free software alternatives are welcome. Game will be a boardgame that is similar to poker. Some technical details are listed below.

- There will be a table which consists of 4 people, to send them message I need a channel manager. A table will be ready to play for at least 5 minutes. There should be a reliable channel manager.
- People will wait for some time(i.e.) and if they are not playing they will be kicked by server, so there will be a reliable timed task queue to execute some tasks.
- It should be quick enough to response and show the changes to all 4 people on that table simultaneously.To achive this server should have a powerfull I/O library.
- I think to use inmemory to have quick response times, but it comes with scalability problems.
- And some variables should be thread safe so a variable should be thread safe between multiple nodes.
- Flash(AS3) and Unity (.Net 2.0 C# mono) client API's should be available for socket connection.

PS: I am using Reddwarf server, it lacks of documentation and multiple node.

Comment: Slightly vague.

Comment: What kind of game are we talking about, and what kind of work would the server have to do? If it's just a simple server that has to show all the available game servers we would advise something completely different then a sharded MMO like server.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I updated the question

Comment: You only added 16 characters, please give a few paragraphs of description that tell us what kind of work the game server will do. What kind of message, what kind of response time, will it have to keep timing similar between clients?

Comment: Hi I have edited the question added technical details of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of game? Assuming you mean an MMORPG, there are no MMORPGs with millions of simultaneous users. There are a few MMORPGs with millions of users, but each logical server only supports a couple of thousand players. EVE Online is an exception in running everything in one logical server, but that has only supported about 60,000 players.

If you mean a game like Farmville, then that is done with multiple servers, but you wouldn't use technology like RedDwarf, but web technology instead, with a lot of distributed caching.

There are lots of MMO middleware companies, but hardly any of them are selling technology that has actually been used in active games, so their concurrency claims are not always useful.

You need to do some research into what is currently feasible and in use, and then be more precise with your requirements.

Comment: Hi, sorry for vague question, it will be an facebook boardgame just like poker. It have a similar game design like texas holdem poker. Users will enter a salon, then sit on a table, will chat, there will be timed actions. Online user count can increase up to tens of thousands of people.

Comment: Ok, in that case a system like RedDwarf is completely the wrong model for you. You have a system where you want thousands of small games with minimal interaction between them. SmartFoxServer might suit you, or maybe the Photon Server.

Answer (score 0):

You want a server that supports millions of players? That doesn't really sound possible, even if an MMO has a million+ users, there are probably only a few thousand online at the same time - and even that requires a whole building for the servers. Basically, that kind of power is only achievable to big corporations like Blizzard, and if you plan to compete with them you better hire some technicians to handle stuff like this. Could you please edit your question?

Final answer: no, there are no games with millions of online users, and no you certainly can't get a server that would support it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for vague question, it will be an facebook boardgame just like poker. It have a similar game design like texas holdem poker. Users will sit on a table, will chat, there will be timed actions.

Comment: Oh, I see. I cannot really help you here, before I thought that Facebook itself hosts those apps, but it obviously doesn't...

Comment: Yes it does not host the apps, We are using a iframe and hosting the app on my server. I edited the question and give technical details above, Kylotan adviced SmartFoxServer or Photon Server. Do you have any idea about them or new suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I have no experience with that, any server software I needed I wrote myself...